# Почему возвращает undefined

Tags: javascript, массивы

Почему `alert` выдает длину массива как `undefined`?

```
var scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18, 41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];
alert(scores.lenght);
```

Answer (score 6):

Ошибка в length. У тебя leng**ht**, а надо leng**th**

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку разобрался!))